# How to pass url as variable to wget..?

Tags: python, wget

I am trying download a page using wget by passing variable which holds url using python,but it didn't work.

```
url=http://www.example.com/support/security/


os.system("wget -P download url")
```

can anyone specify what is wrong with this...?

Comment: You need to specify that url is a variable, not a part of the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python code:

```
import os

url="http://www.adobe.com/support/security/"
os.system('wget %s' %url)
```

Bash code:

```
url="http://www.adobe.com/support/security/"
wget $url
```